# Python Dataframe rename column compared to value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rename

With Pandas I'm trying to rename unnamed columns in dataframe with values on the first ligne of data.

My dataframe:

| id | store | unnamed: 1 | unnamed: 2 | windows | unnamed: 3 | unnamed: 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B1 | B2 | B3 |
| 1 | 2 | c | 12 | 15 | 15 | 14 |
| 2 | 4 | d | 35 | 14 | 14 | 87 |

My wanted result:

| id | store_B1 | store_B3 | store_B2 | windows_B1 | windows_B2 | windows_B3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | B1 | B2 | B3 | B1 | B2 | B3 |
| 1 | 2 | c | 12 | 15 | 15 | 14 |
| 2 | 4 | d | 35 | 14 | 14 | 87 |

I don't know how I can match the column name with the value in my data. Thanks for your help. Regards

Comment: I'm assuming `id` is just the index. Or it is an actual column distinct from the index?

Comment: Hi @richardec, id can be also a column.

Comment: Okay; check my answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `df.columns.where` to make `unnamed:` columns NaN, then convert it to a Series and use `ffill`:

```
df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns.where(~df.columns.str.startswith('unnamed:'))).ffill() + np.where(~df.columns.isin(['id','col2']), ('_' + df.iloc[0].astype(str)).tolist(), '')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id store_B1 store_B2 store_B3 windows_B1 windows_B2 windows_B3
0   0       B1       B2       B3         B1         B2         B3
1   1        2        c       12         15         15         14
2   2        4        d       35         14         14         87
```

Comment: it's possible to use a list of column name instead of one ? df.columns != ['id', 'col2', 'col3']

Comment: Yes. `~df.columns.isin(['id', 'col2', 'col3'])`

Comment: I tried this one : df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns.where(~df.columns.str.startswith('unnamed:'))).ffill() + np.where(df.columns != df.columns.isin(['id','col2']), ('_' + df.iloc[0].astype(str)).tolist(), '')     But I missed something..

Comment: I updated the answer. Basically you want to just say `~df.columns.isin(['id','col2'])`, not `df.columns != df.columns.isin(['id','col2'])`.

Comment: Thanks really much ! It working really well !!